# How to modify manytomany field for each object in a Queryset hitting the database as few as possible

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two models: Pattern and Category. 
Pattern has a manytomany field `categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='patterns')`

My view gets a queryset of categories from a form. I need to get all patterns marked with that categories and delete those categories from `categories` field of every pattern.

Now I'm doing it as follows:

```
patterns_to_remove_category = Pattern.objects.all()
for category in categories:
    patterns_to_remove_category = patterns_to_remove_category.filter(categories=category)

for pattern in patterns_to_remove_category:
    pattern.categories = pattern.categories.exclude(pk__in=[c.pk for c in categories])
```

But I want to minimize number of hits to database. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use implicit `through` model and do query like this:

```
Pattern.categories.through.objects.filter(category__in=categories).delete()
```

Comment: django shell returns the following:

Comment: failed: django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: (1235, "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'")

Comment: Can you please post an output `Pattern.categories.through.objects.filter(category__in=categories).all().query.__str__()` ?

Comment: alternatively, you can replace `filter(category__in=categories)` with `filter(category_pk__in=[c.pk for c in categories])`

Comment: Thank You! That worked! I've just chaged the query, so finally it looks like: **Pattern.categories.through.objects.filter(category_id__in=[c.pk for c in categories]).delete()**

Comment: @ialibekov in fact, you should do `filter(category_id__in=categories.values_list('id', flat=True))` if `categories` is queryset.